# Inbox api use them to tag relevant mails just like inboxsdk.com

Tags: python, api, google-inbox

I tried using newly released Inbox api to sort out and tag my mails, but I am stuck at categorising mails after I had successfully logged in using api.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure where exactly you are struck , but please refer to the following document https://www.inboxsdk.com/docs/#ComposeView though it is documented in javascript